# Trying to draw vertical line down middle of live video frame using opencv (c++)

Tags: c++, opencv

This seems like it should be perfectly simple, but for some reason my line isn't centered - it's farther to the left than it should be.

Here's my code:

```
static const int width = 240;
static const int height = 320;

VideoCapture cap(0);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height);

//Set points for center line
CvPoint mid_bottom, mid_top;
mid_bottom.x = width/2;
mid_bottom.y = 0;
mid_top.x = width/2;
mid_top.y = height;

//for purposes not related to this issue, I have to use IplImages instead of Mats
Mat frame; //(edit - forgot this declaration before, sorry!)
cap >> frame;
IplImage frame_ipl = frame;

//drawing the line
cvLine(&frame_ipl, mid_bottom, mid_top, RED, 2);
```

[image: The result:]

Any thoughts as to why this is going wrong?

Comment: Your camera seems not to be able to generate images with the specified dimensions (the picture you've posted is not 240x320).

Comment: Also, in the future please post the [declarations](http://sscce.org) of all the variables you use. It cuts down on potential ambiguity and lets the people trying to help copy-paste the code and have something run.

Comment: @Niko - Good catch, I hadn't noticed that.
Aurelius - Sorry about that. I guess I've been staring at the code for this project for so long that I cut out a little too much. I'll edit the post and add any declarations missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Niko astutely observed, your camera may not be able to provide frames of the specified dimensions. You can check the value returned by `set()` to see if it was successfully created. If not, it will return `false`.

```
    bool wset = cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width);
    bool hset = cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height);
    if (!wset || !hset)
    {
        std::cout << "Image dimension could not be set" << std::endl;
        // Handle error...
    }
```

A more general approach is to define the line in terms of the actual image dimensions, which allows it to work on arbitrary images:

```
    CvPoint mid_bottom, mid_top;
    mid_bottom.x = frame_ipl.width/2;
    mid_bottom.y = 0;
    mid_top.x = frame_ipl.width/2;
    mid_top.y = frame_ipl.height;
```

Comment: Your general approach works! Strangely enough, however, wset and hset are both true...I'll have to do some more investigating to figure out why that is. Thanks for your help!